# SQLAlchemy and FastAPI throwing "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" error

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mariadb, fastapi

I'm making a Python API using FastAPI with SQLAlchemy, I didn't experience any problems in my local environment, but the problem came when my team tested the API in a QA environment with multiple users at the same time, sometimes the endpoints doesn't throw any errors, but in some cases I got this error:

```
ERROR:sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool:Exception during reset or similar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pogen/Informatica/envs/retail-api/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 988, in _finalize_fairy
    fairy._reset(
  File "/home/pogen/Informatica/envs/retail-api/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1436, in _reset
    pool._dialect.do_rollback(self)
  File "/home/pogen/Informatica/envs/retail-api/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 691, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
  File "/home/pogen/Informatica/envs/retail-api/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 517, in rollback
    self._cmysql.rollback()
```

This is an example of the project structure:

```
.
└── root_folder/
    ├── connection.py
    ├── methods.py
    └── endpoints.py
```

First I define the engine and a function to yield a SQLAlchemy Seesion in the **connection.py** file

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, URL
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

database_url = URL.create(
    "mariadb+mysqlconnector",
    username = 'my_username',
    password = 'my_password',
    host = 'db_host',
    port= 3306,
    database= 'some_database'
)   

database_engine = create_engine(database_url)

def db_connection() -> Session:
    try:
         db_session = sessionmaker(bind= database_engine)
         session = db_session()
         yield session
    finally:
        session.close()
```

The **methods.py** file contains all the database operations, here I call the db_connection function inside the class constructor:

```py
from connection.py import db_connection

class Student:
      def __init__(self):
          self.session = next(db_connection())
      
      def get(std_id):
          pass
      ....
```

Finally in the **endpoints.py** file In the function I instance the class as one Dependency to make all the operations:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, Query
from methods.py import Student
from typing import Annotated

router = APIRouter(prefix='/student')

@router.get('/search_student/')
async def search_student(std_id : Annotated[int,Query(description='Student ID')],
                         student_object : Annotated[Student, Depends(Student)]):
      my_student = student_object.get(std_id)
      return my_student
```

I've already tried adding a pool in the engine but I get the same error

`database_engine = create_engine(database_url, pool_size=20, max_overflow=10)`

Comment: A connection per `db_connection()` in `Student` looks wrong. The connection should be in the scope of the web request so that multiple web requests aren't using the same connection object.